Computing De Rham cohomology directly
I would like to understand how to compute the de Rham cohomology directly, that is, without using Meyer Vietoris theorem. All the examples I saw for the direct computation were very simple.
If we consider $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ or $S^1 \times S^1$, then I know how to approach it using the Meyer Vietoris theorem, there also many references (e.g. the answer here). Any starting points as to how to compute these directly?
Edit: for the case of $\mathbb{R} \times S^1$, I believe that this manifold is diffeomorphic to the punctured plane, which has a direct computation here. This leaves the torus.

What does "compute" mean? Do you intend to guess the answer and then prove "directly" that it is correct?

Yes - but it's not about the answers but more of how to directly derive the results, with differentials etc rather than using the Theorem mentioned.

Why don't you use duality and de rham theorem.

In general, you cannot hope to succeed without tools. You can do $S^1$ directly (without Mayer-Vietoris). Presumably you've done this. But have you done $S^n$ for $n>1$ directly? I can do $S^1\times S^1$ "directly" only by knowing the answer and then proving it is correct.
